# replace tabs in all string jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

i have string and i need to replace tabs (white space) with "|"..the function work fine but the problem is there is more than one tab together so it show like this
( this||is|||text|||| )
and what i need is  ( this|is|text ) here is example.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var text = $(".para").text();
  $(".result").text(text.replace(/\t/g, "|"));
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <p class="para">
        Aa aa  Aaa aa
  Bb bb Bb bb  Bbb bb bb
    cc cccc C ccccc 
      dd  Dd d
  Ee e    
      fff  fff
  </p>
  
  <p class="result"></p>
</div
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a regex with the `g` flag:

```
myString.trim().replace(/\t+/g, '|')
```

The `+` indicator groups all the `\t` together. Also do a `.trim()` to remove the spaces at beginning/end